# php foreach Iteration through json

Tags: php, json, foreach

Assume that I have below json response fetched from an API.

```
{
    "owner": "Jane Doe",
    "pets": [
        {
            "color": "white",
            "type": "cat"
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "type": "dog"
        }
    ]
}
```

From the below PHP code I have converted the json string into a json object. And displayed the pet types.

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($json);

foreach($jsonObject->pets as $pets){
    echo 'Pet type:'.$pets->type.'</br>';
}
```

However in some cases the response json from the API is in below format

```
{
    "owner": "John Doe",
    "pets": {
        "color": "white",
        "type": "cat"
    }
}
```

in this case above php foreach iteration fails with below message

***Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ***

I'm looking for a easy way to do this because the actual json response which i'm handling has lot of these occurrences.

Comment: Why say `Therefore, provide a solution to access the variables from the above json response without using ` ? why **cant** you use an if statement?

Comment: I'm looking for a easy way to do this because the actual json response which i'm handling has lot of these occurrences

Comment: The easiest way to check if something is an array or not is to use an if statement and is_array. If you need to do something a lot, put it in a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check whether `$jsonObject->pets` is an array or object. If it's an object, replace it with an array containing that object, then the loop will work.

```
if (!is_array($jsonObject->pets)) {
    $jsonObject->pets = array($jsonObject->pets);
}
```

You could also do it with a conditional in the `foreach`:

```
foreach (is_array($jsonObject->pets) ? $jsonObject->pets : [jsonObject->pets] as $pet) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to have to write all that every time, you could put it in a function:

```
function as_array($x) {
    return is_array($x) ? $x : [x];
}
```

and then use:

```
foreach (as_array($jsonObject->pets) as $pet) {
    ...
}
```

I'd also complain to the API designer. It's ridiculous to return inconsistent data formats like this.

Comment: For some reason he doesn't want to use Is_array() any reasoning op?

Comment: So, is this the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Well then seems like this is the best way to do this. Sorry about the struggle but i wanted to be skeptical about this.